# Can we enable 'Sign in with Google' for Google Identity Platform multi-tenants programmatically?

Tags: google-signin, multi-tenant, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

As a B2B SaaS provider, we currently create and manage tenants from Google Identity Platform. As we expect to grow, we would like to automate the tenant creation flow with Sign in with Google.

However, I found that Identity Platform Admin SDK doesn't support social sign-in method(including Google), only available using the Cloud console.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LojG6.png)

Is there any programmatic way to enable Sign in with Google for multi-tenancy environment?

We expect to provide different sign in page for each tenant as they might need own branding.

Given new Google Identity Services APIs just announced, other solutions also welcome. Thanks!

Reference :[Managing Identity Platform tenants programmatically document]
[Table shows what sign-in methods you can configure using the Admin SDK and the Cloud Console in a tenant-specific context:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LojG6.png)

Answer (score 2):

We've implemented it so you can try our code and do it also.

This is an example to enable Google SSO for a specific tenant

```
gcp_project = YOUR_PROJECT_ID
google_client_id = YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
google_client_secret = YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET

def enable_google_idp(self, tenant_id: str):
    """
    Enables the Google SSO for a tenant

    :param tenant_id: the id of the tenant
    """
    app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()
    tenant_url = f"projects/{gcp_project}/tenants/{tenant_id}"
    url = f"https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/{location}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs?idpId=google.com&key={api_key}"
    payload = {
        "clientId": google_client_id,
        "clientSecret": google_client_secret,
        "enabled": True,
        "name": f"projects/{gcp_project}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/google.com"
    }
    authenticated_session = google.auth.transport.requests.AuthorizedSession(app.credential.get_credential())
    resp = authenticated_session.post(url=url, json=payload)
    # raise if something failed
    resp.raise_for_status()
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks for building it and sharing the example to implement it. We will try to adopt it. Meanwhile, if there is any updated documents about it, please feel free to share it with us. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using an [intermediate iframe](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/amp/intermediate-iframe), specifically the section entitled **One Tap Displaying Domains**.  It seems like it may help out here.

Now, if you're trying to individually brand the application name and logo which is displayed on the OAuth consent screen for each tenant you'll need to create, and verify a separate project for each tenant/domain. OAuth [brand verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) is not a process suitable for automation.

In summary if you'll need to tightly control the branding you'll [create a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects), get if verified and your tenant will have a custom name and logo. Otherwise, you should be able to quickly onboard and support multiple domains using an intermediate iframe.